# How to display checked radio button on Modal?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel

I have this edit modal, that when I load it, it loads all the other fields, except the radio button one.
I tried loading it with the two commands listed below but had no luck.
Is there something I'm missing for it to work?

```
<div class="text-center">
                                <div class="w3-row">
                                    <label for="event_category">Event Category:</label>
                                    <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="event_category" id="event-category" value="C">
                                    <label>Competition</label>    
                                    <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="event_category"  id="event-category" value="F">
                                    <label>Fundraiser</label>    
                                    <br>
                                    <input class="w3-radio" type="radio"  name="event_category" id="event-category" value="P">
                                    <label>Practice</label>
                                    <input class="w3-radio" type="radio"  name="event_category" id="event-category" value="O">
                                    <label>Other</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

```
$('#event_category').prop('checked',event.event_category);
```

```
$('#event_category').val("input[name='radio']:checked");
```

Comment: do you want `<input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="event_category" id="event-category" value="C">` to be checked when its loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each input element needs unique ID. (No IDs should be repeated in any HTML document).

```
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="w3-row">
        <label for="event_category">Event Category:</label>
        <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="event_category" id="event-category-C" value="C">
        <label>Competition</label>    
        <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="event_category"  id="event-category-F" value="F">
        <label>Fundraiser</label>    
        <br>
        <input class="w3-radio" type="radio"  name="event_category" id="event-category-P" value="P">
        <label>Practice</label>
        <input class="w3-radio" type="radio"  name="event_category" id="event-category-O" value="O">
        <label>Other</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Needed radio button can be queried by ID and set to checked.

```
$("#event-category-P").prop("checked", true);
```

For example if you have value in a `event_category` variable, you can append it to the selector:

```
let event_category = 'P';
$("#event-category-" + event_category).prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: I followed your recommendations and it worked for me, Thanks! 
I think my confusion came because I thought that since it was a group of radio buttons they needed to have the same ID's. Thanks for clarifying that for me.